# Azure master branch doesnt show the merged commits

Tags: azure-devops

We are using Azure DevOps, recently came across the issue when some of the commits that was stated to be completed and merged to the master branch dont show up in Repos history.

Comment: Is there any update for this issue? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help. Just a reminder of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

> Azure master branch doesnt show the merged commits

It depends on the merge method you choose when you PR.

Azure Repos has several merge strategies, and by default, all of them are allowed. You can maintain a consistent branch history by enforcing a merge strategy for PR completion.

[image]

So, if you select the **Squash merge**, which is a merge option that allows you to condense the Git history of topic branches when you complete a pull request. Instead of each commit on the topic branch being added to the history of the default branch, a squash merge adds all the file changes to **a single new commit** on the default branch.

In this case, the commits that was stated to be completed and merged to the master branch dont show up in Repos history.

You could check the document [Merge strategies and squash merge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/merging-with-squash?view=azure-devops) for some more details.